# How do I open a file in the command line arguments?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I have to create a program that **read files** and my professors will test it in the **command line**.

The argument, he will put to open a file, will be a `String`. But he said that the file should open **with or without** the `.txt` extension.

- I would like to know what can be the condition for the name of the file?

I was thinking if `args[0]` does not contain `.txt` add it, but I have no idea how to do this in code.

Comment: Please show what you have attempted.

Comment: Your problem description is not very clear. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What are the requirements to your code?

Answer (score 2):

> I was thinking if args[0] does not contain .txt add it, but I have no
>   idea how to do this in code.

```
if (args[0].endsWith(".txt")) {
  openFile(args[0]);
} else {
  openFile(args[0] + ".txt");
}
```